# Обработка запроса с параметрами на python сервере

Tags: python, json, веб-программирование

Есть функция-обработчик запросов, такого вида:

```
def appcmd_handler(cmd):
    if cmd == 'status':
        return json.dumps({"type": "state", "deviceId": "someid", "ledState": 1, "Параметр": "Что-то еще", "Разберемся" : "потом"})
    return "OK"
```

А теперь предположим, что я ввожу строку такого вида:

`settitle?guid=...&title=...`

Троеточия - параметры, задаваемые пользователем (не обязательно целочисленные).
Возвращаемое значение в случае успеха будет примерно таким:

`{"status": "OK", "guid": "...", "title": "..."}`

Как такое провернуть?

Comment: Это очень похоже на `GET`-параметры `HTTP`-запроса. Я бы использовал соответствующий парсер.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пожалуй так и сделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для парсинга GET параметров можно использовать requests

```
import requests
url = 'http://yoursite.com/settitle?guid=23564734&title=title'
query = requests.utils.urlparse(url).query
params = dict(x.split('=') for x in query.split('&'))
```

Далее используйте свои обработчики для проверки params и формирования своего ответа.